# Rotating Spirals

Tags: code-golf, string

Given a square of text representing a spiral of characters, rotate it!

The spiral starts at the center and moves *counterclockwise* to the outer edge, starting to the left of center:

```
987
216
345
```

This translates to the string `123456789`. Rotation is done *to the left*, so if you rotate it one position, it will be `234567891`. This is represented by:

```
198
327
456
```

#### Input

Input consists of the spiral and the distance to rotate it.

Distance will always be a positive integer or zero, and can be capped at your language's data type limit.

The spiral should be taken as a string, with a line delimiter of your choice (including no delimiter). It will always be a square, not including delimiters, and have an odd side length.

Assume all characters are alphanumeric [A-Za-z0-9].

#### Output

Output is the rotated spiral. It should be a square on multiple lines (whether printed or returned).

#### Examples

Input

```
3
tne
atd
bin
```

Output

```
bat
nit
den
```

Input

```
18
efilr
naepo
umshf
tootr
butte
```

Output

```
rettu
omseb
oofft
trliu
hpean
```

This is code golf, with score counted in bytes as usual.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## CJam, <s>45</s> 44 bytes

```
]]l~LqN/{(W%@+\zW%}h;m<{1$,/(W%a@W%z+\s}h;N*
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%5D%5Dl~LqN%2F%7B(W%25%40%2B%5CzW%25%7Dh%3Bm%3C%7B1%24%2C%2F(W%25a%40W%25z%2B%5Cs%7Dh%3BN*&input=18%0Aefilr%0Anaepo%0Aumshf%0Atootr%0Abutte)

### Explanation

The lazy solution: unwrap the spiral, use CJam's built-in array rotation, roll the spiral up again.

```
]]       e# Push [""]. We'll later use this to roll up the spiral.
l~       e# Read the integer and evaluate it.
L        e# Push an empty string: we'll unroll the input into this.
qN/      e# Read the spiral and split it into lines.
{        e# While the top of the stack is truthy...
  (W%    e#   Pull the first line off the spiral and reverse it.
  @+     e#   Pull up the string we've built so far and prepend the reversed line.
  \zW%   e#   Swap with the remaining spiral, and rotate the spiral.
}h       e# This terminates when the centre character has been added to the string and
         e# the spiral becomes an empty array.
;        e# Discard the empty array.
         e# Note that we've unrolled the spiral from outside in, but we've also built up
         e# the string in reverse, which gives us the string from inside out.
m<       e# Rotate to the left by the given number of characters.
{        e# While the top of the stack is truthy...
  1$,    e#   Copy the spiral so far and get the number of lines.
  /      e#   Split the string into chunks of that size.
  (W%a   e#   Pull off the first chunk, reverse it and wrap it in an array.
  @zW%   e#   Pull up the spiral so far, rotate it.
  +      e#   Prepend the chunk to the spiral as a line.
  \s     e#   Swap with the other chunks and flatten them into a string again.
}h       e# This terminates when the string has been used up completely.
;        e# Discard the empty string.
N*       e# Join the lines with linefeed characters.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 188 bytes

```hs
import Data.List;r=reverse;t=transpose;f=take;g=drop
u[[c]]=[c];u(a:b)=a++u(r.t$b)
w k[]=k;w[](a:b)=w[[a]]b;w k l=w((r.f h$l):(t.r$k))$g h l where h=length k
s n=w[].(\s->g n s++f n s).r.u
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYuxbsQgEER7f8XqRGFkBSlddIhUKfMHhALn1sYCg7Usx@f7HKWZN9KbCb5GTOk8t/0oxPDl2avvrbImQ/hEqqjZMPlcj3L1xbCPqFfzoHIMzdpf58wVuo3@Pkvjp6mNpFjMcugQrTNRd@v@ZbfWOzfrS0AyfbyGCwSR5H1kRSJKKVYIkKAHJIRgEuaVA8ShQr7eTo0/9e1zhQx1mpY/SEWqnbvfsjloyywqvH@IXuhRb7hsiSB7PAq0vYYFuBQmmBsz3s4X)

Answer (score 1):

## Python3, 336 bytes:

```py
R=range
def S(N):
 x,y=N//2,N//2;r=[(x,y)]
 for i in R(2,N,2):
  y-=1;F=0;r+=[(x,y)]
  for X,Y in[(1,0),(0,1),(-1,0),(0,-1)]:
   for _ in R(i):
    if F:x+=X;y+=Y;r+=[(x,y)]
    F=1
 return r
def f(n,s):
 s=[[*i]for i in s.split('\n')];T=[s[x][y]for x,y in S(len(s[0]))];T=T[n:]+T[:n]
 for x,y in S(len(s[0])):s[x][y]=T.pop(0)
 return s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/NbgIhFIX3PAW7gQ7qoP2xM2Hr0oXOQkNJoxEqiWUIYOI8/RSo2ph0c5N7z3dOzrV9OHZmNrduGFbM7cyXBAep4BotcQ3ghfRsOZlMSRqNYxzFCxYAqs5BDbWBKxRFMk0w7EeMNgtWNa78IzO6IdsIc0RJhQmqCI1zdFtGFItkz@Tnb6jOgRBqBRf1pWSbpi/Z9jEYwgWjADoZzs5Al3srZIhPXs84f9Li3tOPvT3pgIoPU2DRtIx7fhG8z0RMTMwanaRBnlcCZ6TlphZly2tz/fgfrr7GsHZsO4sqfC/kB@u0CUjFr4uieJ@/gSl9BbPnl7hhDG7qLKnBSLALB7DX5lGl8yRLpU8OmJ20HTh/@6MCoeuCA/tzCDIbhh8)

Comment: [320 bytes](https://tio.run/##VY/NbsIwEITv@xS@xW4MxKE/NJGvnBAHyAHkWhUIu1iijmUbKXn6NAkFictKuzPf7qxr47m284XzXbfh/mB/FJyURlu8JgWghrd8PZvlpee4oS2hgHTtkUHGog3O6Zrmgw21E87KJc9Knz6Mo3NH94MXM5oRijPK@jq5NxM2wqPx@7bS3CbIaLQsmpTvyjbl@6e1CC05A@RVvHqL/BhXY0vDgAYuxIuRj5BhGtzFRJx82YTIcsW3@KIsDiKThJQVF0E0UrQj0B8YkJXs55WwhUwrUVh5e/kuFv8Ar6audjgjjyShc97YiHX/bJIkn4sPyNk7zF/f@o4QuKvzQY1WwSGe4Gjss8oWg6y0uXiwB@VquP6Gs4ZY19HD8RqjGoHuDw)